Is a Gaussian process with covariance $C''(0)=0$ allowed?
Let $y(t)$ be a zero mean, homogeneous isotropic Gaussian process:
$$
\left<y\right>=0 \qquad,\qquad \left<y(t_1)y(t_2)\right>=C(t_2-t_1)
$$
where $\left< \dots \right>$ denotes averaging over realizations of $y$. I am interested in the case $C(t)$ being differentiable many times- in particular $C(t)\neq \delta(t)$. Let me state directly that $C(t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$ and $C(t)=C(-t)$. I've noticed that several properties of $y$ end up depending on $C''(0)$. For example, Rice's formula for the zero-crossing rate.
My questions are about Gaussian processes for which $C''(0)=0$. Do they have a special name? Are kernels with $C''(0)=0$ disallowed on some theoretical grounds? A simple example is $C(t)=(1+t^4)^{-1}$.
My thoughts: processes with $C''(0)=0$ appear to be 'essentially constant': the difference process $\epsilon d(t)=y(t+\epsilon)-y(t)$ has zero mean and a covariance that vanishes for small $\epsilon$
$$
C_d(\epsilon)\propto\epsilon^2 \qquad,\qquad\epsilon\to0
$$
so the derivative process $y'(t)$ appears to be constant and equal to zero (the variance at any time vanishes). This is why I suspect such processes are 'not well behaved' in some sense.

Let $y'(t)$ be the derivative of $y(t)$ in the mean-square sense. Note that $$Cov(y'(s), y'(t)) = \frac{d}{ds}\frac{d}{dt}Cov(y(s), y(t)) = -C''(s - t).$$
Hence
$$C''(0) = -Var(y'(t)).$$
If $C''(0) = 0$, then $y'(t) = 0$ for all $t$, so $y(t) = y(0)$ for all $t$. It follows that $C(t) = Cov(y(0), y(0)) = Var(y(0))$ for all $t$. That means your $(1 + t^4)^{-1}$ is not positive-definite. Indeed, it seems like the Fourier transform is negative for some values.
